# Creating a Master Query module for Mongoose (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am writing a master query function module for mongoose where I can just pass information and it will do the dirty work for me. I got tired of writing queries so this is my solution.

I do have it working, and this particular way will work, but I feel like I can remove the if statement and use the variable straight up, my knowledge of this stuff is still fairly slim though, so maybe there isn't really a way to do it.

So here is the call:

```
let options = { _id: socket.handshake.session.passport.user };
let q = {};
let user = await query("User", "findOne", options, q);
```

Here is the function for it:

```
const q = async (c, t, o, q) => {
  c = require(`../models/${c}`);
  let query;
  if (t == "findOne") {
    query = c.findOne(o, q);
  }
  return await query
    .exec()
    .then(results => {
      return results;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return console.log(err);
    });
};

module.exports = q;
```

Like this is works flawlessly, but I feel like I can still make it better. I'd like to be able to use `t` directly instead of using it in a if statement.

```
c = collection (User)
t = type (the query, findOne is the only one atm)
o = options (or in this case the selector)
q = query (what I want changed, if applicable)
```

*This is for reference

I'm not terribly against writing all the statements out if need be, but if I can I'd like to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah HA! I got it! The function look like so:

```
const q = async (c, t, o, q) => {
  c = require(`../models/${c}`);
  let query = c[t](o, q);
  return await query
    .exec()
    .then(res => {
      return res;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return console.log(err);
    });
};

module.exports = q;
```